# What could be that site suddenly returns System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: Unspecified error?

Tags: .net, database, ms-access

My ASP site based on MS-Access stopped working. When it tries to open the connection I get error `System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: Unspecified error`. The website and the access file is located on the same server.

No updates or changes were made in the server. The connection string wasn't changed. The **mdb** file isn't missing.

Any suggestion what could possibly happen?

**P.S.** for that that the site could use "mdb" file, do I really need MS-Office be installed on the server or .Net framework is enough?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need Office or Access, but the Jet-Engine, which belongs to Windows, not to Office.

As for the error: Try to repair the mdb. Sometimes they just get corrupted.